# facebook api marketing create campaign issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to create a campaign using Facebook API. I tried to run all available example without success.

First of all I created an App in order to have a APP_ID and a APP_SECRET.

I did all the procedure to add my Ad_account following the tutorial.

I downloaded all the SDK to facilitate Facebook API use like:

1. [facebook-php-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk)  and run adgroup_creation.php and curl_log.php with my data, without success.
2. [facebook-php-sdk-v4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) I suppose it is less specific than the previous one.
3. Multi-Product Ads with the Facebook Marketing POST -> developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2015/03/26/creating-multi-product-ads/
4. the developers reference -> developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

I used "Composer" to get all dependency.

In all this case I had problem to create a campaign using more or less this code:

```
$campaign = new \FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign(null,"act_$ACCOUNT_ID");

$campaign->setData(array(
AdCampaignFields::NAME => 'My First Campaign',
AdCampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => AdObjectives::WEBSITE_CLICKS,
AdCampaignFields::STATUS => AdCampaign::STATUS_PAUSED ));

// PROBLEM is Here 
$campaign->create();
```

Any help? How can I get a more useful error?

Comment: You're not catching or showing the error received from the API, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help without knowing the exact error. However, you could try this: before creating your campaign, initialize the API using:

```
Api::init(<your_app_id>, <your_ap_secret>, <your_token>);
```

(You need to load FacebookAds\Api to use this function).